# Perform action after request is successful

Tags: angular

I want to call a function after a post request ends successfully. How to achieve that?

This is my post request:

```
this.http.post(this.myUrl, formData, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
    .subscribe(
    data => console.log('success'),
    error => console.log(error)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `{}` in your callback you can add as much code as you want.

```
this.http.post(this.myUrl, formData, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
    .subscribe(
    data => { 
      // you can do everything you want here
      console.log('success');
      this.myCustomFunction();
    },
    error => console.log(error)
)
```

Comment: This causes "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" error in console.

Comment: I double checked and the syntax is correct. Are you coding with Typescript?

Comment: I suspect that the response is not actually a JSON string, so the exception is caused by the `res.json()` line.

Comment: It could be. He did not specify which console (IDE or browser ?).

Comment: I get that error in the browser. The type returned from the server is HttpResponseMessage from System.Net.Http, is it possible that it causes the problem since it's not json?

Comment: Print your response in the console. If it's not JSON then you can't decode as if it was JSON. You are not forced to decode it as JSON. You can do whatever you want with your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
   this.http.post(this.myUrl, formData, options)
   .map(res => res.json())
   .subscribe(
     (data) =>  {   
      console.log('success');
      this.myFunction(); //call any function
     },   
     (error) => {
       console.log(error)
     });
```

http.post(...).map(...) return a Observable, .subscribe(...) it is a process asynchronous, if you want to invoke a function after http response you must do it inside of subscribe in the function

```
(data) => { // inside invoke the function  that you want}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma after first "}" character? But is causes "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" error in console.